# Is it okay for the last line of a paragraph to be a broken sentence of the next title?

Tags: essay

I am writing an essay for a course with the title 'A day in the life', I have never thought about doing this before but for some reason I am running with it. What are your thoughts for something like the below:

```
So that’s what my company does but…


**Where do I fit in?**
```

I was thinking about doing this throughout the essay but as it's not something I've done before I'm not sure whether to do this as a one of, none of or a running theme. So essentially is it ever okay to have the last sentence of a paragraph a broken sentence with an ellipsis which is completed by the next tile?

What are your thoughts?

Comment: As a pattern, it could be seen as too cute (precious). I'd prefer:  So that’s what my company does, but where do I fit in? Then the following title repeats "Where Do I Fit In?"

Comment: Interesting, what do you think of rhetorical questions as the last sentence? 'That's enough about me for now, what exactly is 'mycompany' and what do they do? Title.. 'All about mycompany'
Does one read better than the other? i.e. the rhetorical question or the emphasis of the title in the last sentence as you suggested above, or would you say having a variance would avoid being too 'precious'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Over-cute, a Little pretentious, but Unique enough to potentially work:

I can totally see someone thinking this is too clever, and it's definitely an obnoxiously cute idea. It's not proper English and for a class, that may mean it will be poorly graded. BUT it is fairly unique, and in the world of writing today, unique at least stands out. If your audience appreciates character and personal expression, and is willing to overlook just how clever it's being, it will make your work stand out.

So really, it's entirely about your audience. If it's for a class, ASK the professor if they appreciate experimental techniques. If they do, you're set. If they tell you you're deviating from the formula and will be graded accordingly, then there's your answer.

Comment: Thanks man, thankfully 1) it's not an English essay, it's for a Data Analysis course so hopefully I can get away with it. 2) I can submit a couple of drafts before submission so I guess I'll get some feedback from the first draft. I am trying to deviate slightly from the status quo, mainly by adding a slight bit of humor in the opening Introduction; with the readers in mind. I mean they must be bored to death reading so many of these 10-20 page essays about a day in someone's life, might as well try stand out/make it a little bit different. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks. For future reference, it's good etiquette to upvote right away, but wait to accept an answer until about 24 hours after asking (because you can get answers from people all around the world and with all sorts of schedules). Accepting an answer means people are less likely to give you additional (potentially better) answers.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin Thank you, I didn't notice the error.

Answer (score -2):

Honestly, I'm not sure if it's OK for an essay. But creativity it sounds great. You can tell how your character feels.